# Convert specific string values to specific numeric values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe called `df` with a `_type` column, containing either `First` or `Second`.  I'd like to convert all `First` values to 1 and all `Second` values to 2.

How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with a dictionary:

```
df['_type'] = df['_type'].map({'First': 1, 'Second': 2})
```

---

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        '_type': ['First', 'Second', 'First', 'Second']
    })

df
#   _type
#0  First
#1  Second
#2  First
#3  Second

df['_type'] = df['_type'].map({'First': 1, 'Second': 2})

df
# _type
#0  1
#1  2
#2  1
#3  2
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.replace` works:

```
In [10]: df._type.replace(('First', 'Second'), (1, 2), inplace=True); df
Out[10]: 
   _type
0      1
1      2
2      1
3      2
```

---

Another possibility with `df.eq` (not inplace):

```
In [15]: df._type.eq('Second').mul(1) + 1 
Out[15]: 
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
Name: _type, dtype: int64
```

---

You can also use `np.where`:

```
In [28]: pd.Series(np.where(df._type == 'First', 1, 2)).to_frame('_type')
Out[28]: 
   _type
0      1
1      2
2      1
3      2
```

Comment: Look at my answer, If you want something new LOL

Answer (score 1):

My solution is come from way i achieve it in R by using `factor`.

In python `pandas` should be `category`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'_type': ['First', 'Second', 'First', 'Second']})
df['_type'].astype('category').cat.codes.add(1)  


Out[706]: 
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
dtype: int8
```

Comment: Very nice! Learned something new. +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, just a trick from R , after 0.15 pandas , pandas have it too~ already upvoted for u